# Does a player get dealt a card if they fold out of turn?

Tags: rules, home-game, seven-card-stud

At a recent friendly poker night that I hosted, playing Seven Card Stud a player had called a bet then folded his hand before the dealer could deal him his next card.  There was disagreement at the table as to whether or not the player should receive their next card.  Some felt that the player should receive another card because they had folded out of turn while others felt that the player's hand was dead and they should not receive another card.  At the time, the dealer ruled the latter, the player did not receive another card, and the hand was completed.

The issue is not the status of the player's hand (all agreed they had folded), just should they have been dealt another card?

Comment: Worth pointing out that so long as the extra card isn't revealed, whether that person is dealt the extra card or not will not affect anyone else's odds.

Comment: As it happened, we were playing a 7-card game, the card was an up-card that was dealt to the next player and players could see the remaining up-cards that they would have been dealt if the folder had received the card.

Comment: Type of game and more detail IN the question please.

Comment: Standard casino rules are that the dead hand does continue to receive cards (up or down as appropriate) until it is properly folded in turn.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker thanks I will edit that into the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actual rulings with this are going to vary. Seven card stud is not a very common game anymore so a lot of places do not even have the situation come up but once in a blue moon.

Technically the rule was in the old days "or at least the custom" was your were not allowed to fold in this manner, and if a floor person was called over they would tell you so. It was about as serious as acting out of turn in holdem and sometimes used as an angle to help a friend by giving them information. The other problem with it was that it changed the lay of the cards in a way done out of normal play, and this tended to upset stud players. So the standard is to deal cards to the spot.

I suggest you let your players know that it is against your house rules if they fold like this, comes under being disruptive to the game. It is a rude thing to do.

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful! :-)  I am considering a house rule to try to prevent "out of turn" play.